# Windows azure project replace ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild

I have two MVC projects. And I created two WindowsAzure project:WindowsAzure1-> which package MVC1 , and WindowsAzure2-> which package MVC2 project. After CheckIn on Local TFS 2012, I build my solution. MSBuild Arguments:

> /t:Publish /p:PublishDir=c:\drops\app.publish\

After Build I see 3 file, instead 4.

> 1.WindowsAzure1.cspkg
>   2.WindowsAzure2.cspkg
>   3.ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg//It contain config WindowsAzure2.cspkg

I tried to rename ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg, but it doesn't rename.
So, I think the better place package on different folder. But problem that in the future MVC and Azure project will be unknown count. So I need automatically create folder contains name project. So how can it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Way to create dynamic folders is through PowerShell Script.

Lets say you have folder structure of projects in following way - 
[image]

Then you can following script to generate package folders -

```
# Solution directory, which contains all the projects
$path = "C:\Solution"
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $path

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
      if ($folder.Attributes -eq "Directory")
      {
            if($folder.Name -like "*.Cloud")
            {
                New-Item -Path "$($path)\$($folder.Name)package" -ItemType "Directory"
            }
      }
}
```

Output will be - 
[image]

Then you can use CSPack utility and PowerShell combination to create package and save configuration file to the location of your interest.

http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/jumpstart-30-create-azure-cloud-service-package-cspkg-of-visual-studio-2013-project-solution-using-powershell/